# How to refresh SSL certificate for proxy server on port 1337?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache2

I have a domain, which I'll simply refer to as "example.org" for security reasons, running on Amazon EC2 on which I'm trying to get SSL access working.  I'm using letsencrypt and certbot to issue my certificates.  Everything was working fine for the first 90 days until I tried to renew the SSL cert.  I was able to successfully refresh the certificate for my domain name, but for some reason I seem to have a separate certificate for a proxy server I'm using on port 1337 that shows as expired.

When I try to use an app on my site, I see the following error on the JavaScript console in the browser:

```
example.org:1337 uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate expired on Tuesday, October 9, 2018, 7:50 PM. The current time is Friday, October 19, 2018, 3:43 PM.

Error code: <a id="errorCode" title="SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE">SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE</a>
 (unknown)
```

My client app is an Angular 6 SPA that directly communicates with "https://example.org:1337".

Using an [SSL checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) I can see that my "example.org" shows that the domain level certificate will expire in 47 days.  However, when I check on "example.org:1337" it says the certificate expired 13 days ago.  It's my understanding that I only need one SSL certificate per domain and I don't have to individually certify each port.  I did not originally request a certificate for port 1337, but I do have a *proxyPass* specified for it in "/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf":

```
# allow us to call a node server without the user having to specify the port number 
# directly e.g. call the proxy server like it's a standard http route.
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location /servers/meta-data-proxy>
    ProxyPass https://localhost:1337
    ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:1337
</Location>
```

When I SSL check for another port I use, which does not have a proxy, it says "no ssl certificates found", which is what I would expect.

certbot shows the following certificates:

```
> sudo certbot certifictes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: example.org
    Domains: example.org www.example.org
    Expiry Date: 2018-12-09 11:08:32+00:00 (VALID: 47 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem
```

How can I either:
a) Refresh or synchronize the cert on port 1337 to be in sync with the one on the domain name?

b) Somehow delete the expired cert on port 1337 on my machine.  I don't see it listed anywhere according to certbot.  I'm hoping that by deleting it, it will somehow dynamically set things up again.

I'm not even really certain I need to have a "ProxyPass".  It might have been something I just did originally to get things working, but isn't really needed.

Ubuntu 18.04
Apache2 2.4.29

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone: this one falls under the category of never mind/ user error.

Turns out I *did* copy the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem` and `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem` into a subdirectory of my proxy server.  The proxy server listening on port 1337 then loads these files.  Once I refreshed them with the updated versions being used by the main https server, everything worked again.  So in effect, I did have two versions of the keys out there, and you could only figure this out by looking at the code.

I shouldn't really have to remember to do this, and I would say this is a reflection of a bad design on the part of my app.  It's probably not a good idea to have the client directly reference port numbers. I should really have the client reference the server through one port (e.g 443 for SSL) and then have the server decide to redirect to any internal servers.  My app originally was running just http, and I wasn't really thinking that much about security.  Then I added https at the last second. Not being very familiar with SSL, I made it a much harder problem than I had to, so that's my defense.  Ugh.